Can "exports" mean "the amount exported"?
I know "exports" mainly means the products which are exported from a country, but does it also refer to the amount of something exported? For example, do the following sentences mean the same?


The amount of coffee exported from Colombia rose from 5 million units in 2002 to 12 million units in 2012.
Colombia's coffee exports rose from 5 million units in 2002 to 12 million units in 2012.



'Exports' can refer to the amount (or value in money terms) of a thing (or things) exported. Likewise 'imports' for things gong the other way.

Using exports to mean volume of exports (normally referring to dollar value) is in very common use.
From Collins Dictionary

COUNTABLE NOUN
Exports are goods which are sold to another country and sent there.
He did this to promote American exports. 
Ghana's main export is cocoa. 
Synonyms: foreign trade, international trade, overseas trade   More Synonyms of export

